# Deployment Error: Administrator port is occupied by GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.0.1

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I am using Ubuntu Linux VM. I am trying to Deploy my java project in Netbeans and getting below error. I am having two glassfish. One which is from Netbeans and One i have installed. I am not able resolve the following.

I have Apache Webserver which is running.

`Deployment error: Could not start GlassFish Server 4.1.1: Administrator port is occupied by GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  5.0.1  (build 5)
See the server log for details.`

If there is two glassfish server exist in my Machine. I do want to kill or delete one server probably Glassfish 5.0.1.

I tried `asadmin stop-domain domain1` but this gives me following error. `Command 'asadmin' not found, did you mean:`

There must be something that i am missing. Thank you for time and consideration

Comment: Just like the error says, looks like a different version of glassfish (5.0.1) is already running while your application is trying to use 4.1.1 on the same ports.  You could try to kill the 5.0.1 freeing up the ports for your use or you could change your port settings for 4.1.1 to other ports.

Comment: How can i kill the Glassfish 5.0.1 server running?

Comment: @Abel Is there any command to do so

Comment: since it seems you didnt configure it, try: asadmin stop-domain domain1

Comment: @Abel, This gives me `Command 'asadmin' not found` error.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadi.html